# MongoDB: multiple $in on the same field

Tags: mongodb

I want to query mongoDB field for data that is '$in' two lists (arrays) kinda:

```
{user: {$in: [<array1>]} AND user: {$in: [<array2>]}}
```

so the query returns only those 'users' that present in both arrays.

I feel this isn't right:

```
 {user: {$in: [<array1>], [<array2>]}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 'users present in both arrays' Does this mean you only want to find documents where the user is any of the intersection of `array1` and `array2`? If so, can't you simply intersect the arrays client-side before sending the query?

Comment: yes, that's possible. But I wonder if it can be done using mongodb functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you can use the $AND operator.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

```
{'$AND':[ {'user':{$in: [<..array1..>]} },{'user':{$in: [<..array2..>] }  }] }
```

Comment: that might be the answer

Comment: Can you comment on the expected percent overlap of array1 and array2?   I have to run some tests but my gut says mnemosyn is right wrt to client-side intersection.

Comment: (1) won't work because you can't have an object with two `user` keys, but (2) should work.